# Recreate PBL from object files

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm recovering from a backup problem on my TFS server and now i have a bunch of object files, but no library file (PBL) or workspace (PBW).
I need to get back to work with this project, but i cant add it to Powerbuilder anymore.

I'm currently using Powerbuilder 10.2.1.
I've tried to:
1: Create a new Workspace and add the target file to it. (Failed. Says 'Could not add target because of bad application in library in [path-to]\target-file.pbt')

2: Tried to create a new Library File and import all the objects. (Failed. Keeps saying that some variables could not be found.)

I'm aware that there's a great chance that my question is plain dumb, but i'm out of options and i really need to work on this project.

There's anyway to recreate the PBL or to 'rebuild' my project so i can get back to working on it as soon as possible? I'm starting to use PowerBuilder and i've searched everywhere, but with no success.

thanks.

Comment: You may want to consider placing copies of your .pbl files in TFS to help avoid this in the future (once you get a working set of course).

Comment: i do that, but all hell broke lose the day we lost our tfs server.
for ethical reasons, i dont want to get too much into details...
in any case, thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 0):

My Bootstrap utility will do that. It can extract files from source control as well. You can run the 'Import into Libraries' function separately since you already have the files on disk.

http://www.topwizprogramming.com/bootstrap.html

Comment: sorry it took me so long to reply. i'll try your solution today and i'll get back to you asap. :)